# Validating input text field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, onchange

I guess I'm doing a trivial error somewhere but will be grateful if someone can spot it.
I am trying to validate a postcode in a form field once it has been typed in. Similar code works fine in PHP but I've spent hours and the JS does not seem to be executing whatever I do.
Here is part of the form (all within body tags):

```
<form name ="register" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" autocomplete="off">

...


<script  type="text/javascript" src="common.js">
             </script>

<input type="text" name="postcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode" maxlength="10"  value='' onchange="isValidPostcode(this.form)"  required />
```

Here are versions of the javascript (stuffed with alerts just to print out something).
Version 1:

```
function isValidPostcode(form) { 
    alert("called");

             var p = document.register.postcode.value;
             var postcodeRegEx = '/^([g][i][r][0][a][a])$|^((([a-pr-uwyz]{1}([0]|[1-9]\d?))|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[a-hk-y]{1}([0]|[1-9]\d?))|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[1-9][a-hjkps-uw]{1})|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[a-hk-y]{1}[1-9][a-z]{1}))(\d[abd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2})?)$/i'; 
             if (postcodeRegEx.test(p)) alert("OK"); 
             else alert("This does not look a valid UK postcode...");
            }
```

Version 2 (is called without a parameter):

```
function isValidPostcode() { 
    alert("called");
             var p = document.getElementById('postcode').value.replace(/\s/g,''); 

             var postcodeRegEx = '/^([g][i][r][0][a][a])$|^((([a-pr-uwyz]{1}([0]|[1-9]\d?))|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[a-hk-y]{1}([0]|[1-9]\d?))|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[1-9][a-hjkps-uw]{1})|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[a-hk-y]{1}[1-9][a-z]{1}))(\d[abd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2})?)$/i'; 
             if (postcodeRegEx.test(p)) alert("OK"); 
             else alert("This does not look a valid UK postcode...");
            }
```

I tried binding to other events but can't get a single alert out. Even exact reproduction of the examples is not working. Hope someone gives me an idea of what is wrong.

Comment: Start by just passing `this` to `isValidPostcode()` - `this` will be your input field.

Comment: Do you have a `submit` button on form ? Since `onchange` on a text box is fired only when you press return key, I suspect that your return key submits the form instead of triggering the onchange event on the text box, though I'm not sure. Or you can try validating input in form's onsubmit event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should replace onchange with keyup and remove quotes from regex :)

```
<input type="text" name="postcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode" maxlength="10"  value='' onkeyup="isValidPostcode(this.value)"  required />

function isValidPostcode(value) { 
        var postcodeRegEx = /^([g][i][r][0][a][a])$|^((([a-pr-uwyz]{1}([0]|[1-9]\d?))|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[a-hk-y]{1}([0]|[1-9]\d?))|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[1-9][a-hjkps-uw]{1})|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[a-hk-y]{1}[1-9][a-z]{1}))(\d[abd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2})?)$/i; 
         if (postcodeRegEx.test(value)) console.log("OK"); 
         else console.log("This does not look a valid UK postcode...");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. However, none of the suggestions work (and some other weird ideas I tried).  The snippet of Magicprog works, but not when copied into my code. Though it fires on any input, while I need to wait for the input to complete. "onchange" documentation says it fires whenever is cursor moves away from the field (I don't care about copy/paste). Javascript is not disabled, it works in other parts of the code. I am about to give up and do validations in PHP. Comment about quotes in regex was valid, Thanks,

Comment: Solved! Your effort inspired me :) Nothing to do with Javascript. Had to change script location to a relative one, though in the other file in the same folder it works as shown - in the root. I never gave it enough thought as to why a different path to the same file is needed within the same folder.

Comment: Working solution:<input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode" maxlength="4"  value=''  onchange="isValidPostcode(this.value)" required />

Comment: function isValidPostcode(value) { 
    alert("called");
             /* var p = document.getElementById('postcode').value.replace(/\s/g,''); */
             /* var p = document.register.postcode.value; */
             var postcodeRegEx = /^([g][i][r][0][a][a])$|^((([a-pr-uwyz]{1}([0]|[1-9]\d?))|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[a-hk-y]{1}([0]|[1-9]\d?))|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[1-9][a-hjkps-uw]{1})|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[a-hk-y]{1}[1-9][a-z]{1}))(\d[abd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2})?)$/i; 
             if (postcodeRegEx.test(value)) alert("OK"); 
             else alert("This does not look a valid UK postcode...");
            }

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `keyup` event to do that and add the event using JS, not inline it.

`postcodeRegEx` is a regex, not a string, you need to remove quotes around it.

```js
function isValidPostcode() {
    var p = document.getElementById('postcode').value.replace(/\s/g, '');

    var postcodeRegEx = /^([g][i][r][0][a][a])$|^((([a-pr-uwyz]{1}([0]|[1-9]\d?))|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[a-hk-y]{1}([0]|[1-9]\d?))|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[1-9][a-hjkps-uw]{1})|([a-pr-uwyz]{1}[a-hk-y]{1}[1-9][a-z]{1}))(\d[abd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2})?)$/i;

    if (postcodeRegEx.test(p)) alert("OK");
    else alert("This does not look a valid UK postcode...");
}
document.getElementById("postcode").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    isValidPostcode();
});
```

```html
<form name="register" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="postcode" type="text" name="postcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode" maxlength="10" value='' required />
</form>
```